# Convert a decimal number to a letter in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-programming

I have a function that already translates an integer into a letter, I would like to optimize it to translate decimal numbers into letters.

function : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22a67dedd54291d7ffb527e2f9d482ca
Example : 2053.21

i tried :

```
select concat(en_function(2053), ' point',  en_function(21))
```

but it is not good approch
i want to put `select en_function(5423.21)` and return "five thousand four hundred twenty-three point twenty-one"

how can i do that?

Comment: Also notice that `concat(en_function(2), ' point',  en_function(0053))` would probably not have the right output, with the leading zeroes in the decimal part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way would be to write a wrapper function and call the original function twice for real and decimal part of the number inside that wrapper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION en_function2(nombre decimal)
    RETURNS text
AS $BODY$ 
        select case when substring(nombre::text from '[.]') is null or replace(substring(nombre::text from '[.][0-9]*'),'.','')::int = 0 then en_function(nombre)
        else concat(en_function(replace(substring(nombre::text from '[0-9]*[.]'),'.','')::decimal), ' point ', en_function(replace(substring(nombre::text from '[.][0-9]*'),'.','')::decimal))
        end
$BODY$ LANGUAGE sql
```

---

```
select en_function2(2053.21);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f1e3f51cfad2fede4a817db0cfaf0991)*

Comment: there is an error  see : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6fb3c4c95e5d396ae3c246de11aed205 ,

Comment: @FranckWhite no , you need to create a new function called "en_function2" which calls en_function inside , see the fiddle in my answer

Comment: when there is integer number only it return point only

Comment: you just need add a case statement ,I'm checking the existence of . in the given  number